# Using the console as readkey input AND as sink for serilog logging

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console, serilog

I would like to be able to use the console for user command inputs (ex: console.Readkey()). The problem is that a colleague incorporated serilog as our logging method and uses the console as a sink which seems to ignore every Console.Write() or Console.ReadLine() instruction in my C# code.

Is there a way around this without having to create a 2nd console instance?

**EDIT**: here is the extract of the serilog config in my json configuration file

```
"Logging": {
"Using": [
  "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
  "Serilog.Sinks.File",
  "Serilog.Sinks.Debug"
],
"MinimumLevel": "Debug",
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "xxxxxxxx.log",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
      "retainedFileCountLimit": 10,
      "fileSizeLimitBytes": 10240000,
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Debug",
    "Args": {
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the configuration of `serilog`?

Comment: @FelipeOriani thanks for your comment, i added the config. I am not familiar with serilog and someone else did this part thats kinda why im struggling i guess

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the configuration log for the Console and keep just the `File` and `Debug`. Remove it from `Using` and `WriteTo` arrays:

```
"Logging": {
    "Using": [
        "Serilog.Sinks.File",
        "Serilog.Sinks.Debug"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
                "path": "xxxxxxxx.log",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 10,
                "fileSizeLimitBytes": 10240000,
                "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "Debug",
            "Args": {
                "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure but maybe the `Debug` log on Console as well (or on the output window on visual studio). If it is disturbing on the console remove it as suggested on the Console.

Comment: I was hoping I could log on the console and read from it at the same time but if thats not possible I will do as you suggest, thank you

Comment: You could keep `Debug` to see the logs on the `Output Windows` of Visual Studio and keep the Console clean, since it is a console app and console is your UI. I do not think you are able to keep both (log and input).